# Is it possible to let user using android large screen device force the app to run on xlarge screen mode?

Tags: android, screen

i am interested in the possibility of leting the App run in xlarge screen mode while the device has a large screen. That is to say, the user can decide in run time if a phone version or a tablet version should be running on her large screen device. Anyone has an idea?

best regards
Yimei

Answer (score 0):

There isn't anything that supports that kind of functionality within the Android framework. You would have to implement it yourself, by having the user select a type, and loading a different xml layout resource based on their selection.

Eg.

If user selects Tablet, load `"my_layout_tablet.xml"`, otherwise load `"my_layout_phone.xml"`.

Obviously you will need to store their selection in a preference file and load it in every time you load the application, before you need to pick a layout for a particular screen

Answer (score 0):

add this in your manifest.xml   so that your screen size be resizeable.

```
  supports-screens android:resizeable="true"
```